# How do I stop error on vba that has previously worked

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using a simple invoicing system via excel that has been working perfectly for the last 18 months.  I had to have a new processor installed into my laptop yesterday and now I am getting a debug error. I have also installed (pdf hub as this was recommended when I googled the issue).

this is the line I am now getting a debug error on

```
Ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

My error message is:

> Run-time error 1004 file not found?

Every other command is working perfectly on this vba.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Please check if the complete file path (including filename, extension and separator) is valid.

Comment: Going to guess that along with a new CPU, your network drive mappings got deleted or rearranged. If you `? FilePath` in the immediate window, then copy/paste that into the Windows Run command prompt, does it open up the Windows Explorer to that directory, or does it give you an error?

Comment: Hi, that is what happened, it had been rearranged and despite being in the same file etc it had changed and had an additional 'users' in there. Thank you so much for your help.